# How to find a comment entered in Visual Studio when protecting a file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, commit

I have a problem. Normally when I protect files in Visual Studio, I add a comment (I enter a code).

Now I want to look for that code to see what files I protected at that time but I don't know how to do it.

Can somebody help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veQY7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could start using custom tokens that visual studio provides -

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/06/10/create-custom-tokens-for-the-task-list/

That way you can look up all places with your token as if they were TODO references.

As for already existing comments, assuming they are all the same, couldn’t you find them with CTRL+SHIFT, F?

Comment: I activated the 'TODO' option and performed a search but it doesn't work. Find the comments added within the code but not the comments modified when protecting the file.

Comment: Sorry, the TODO option would only be if you decided to use it going forward. It won't work with your current files. What are you using for source control? Also do you mean "comments" as in code comments, or commit comments?

Comment: To source control is using Microsoft Source Safe (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe)

Comment: Apologies but its been a while since I’ve used TFS (I’m assuming you mean TFS as Source Safe was discontinued a while back). Assuming you do use TFS you can try something like this - http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ which will allow you to go back through each change set to compare. Sorry I can’t be of more help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am referring to Source Safe if, in the company we have been implementing it for years and so far the change to TFS has not been considered.